# Code MODULE_NOT_FOUND was returned when a node red node is installed using the HTTP API

Tags: node.js, node-red

Currently I am trying to install node in NodeRED using the HTTP POST /nodes using the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i http://localhost:1880/nodes -d "{\"module\": \"C:\\test\\testRemoteNodeWindow\"}"
```

But I am getting a 400 Bad request response, this one:

> {"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Cannot find module 'C:\test\testRemoteNodeWindow'"}

But I have noticed that the node was added as dependency to the node_red_config/package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-red-project",
  "description": "A Node-RED Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "testRemoteNodeWindow": "file:testRemoteNodeWindow"
 }
}
```

And the symbolic link was created in node_red_config/node_modules, the issue only is happening in Windows the strange is that I am using the same node/node-red/npm version in a Linux machine and the node is created using the HTTP POST /node without any problem. Does anyone know if this can be a configuration problem or something like that?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, this regarding with the Windows path for example I use:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:1880/nodes -d "{\"module\": \"C:/test/testRemoteNodeWindow\"}"
```

The node is installed and I am getting HTTP 200 response but if I use:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i http://localhost:1880/nodes -d "{\"module\": \"C:\\test\\testRemoteNodeWindow\"}"
```

I got the MODULE_NOT_FOUND code.

Answer (score 0):

The `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error means that whilst it has successfully run the `npm install` of your module, the runtime has then failed to find a valid Node-RED module with that name.

This usually means your module does not have a `node-red` section in its `package.json` file, as described [here](https://new.nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/packaging#packagejson). Without that, the runtime does not recognise the module as a valid Node-RED module.

Comment: But exactly the same node is being installed in a NodeRed server that is running on Linux and NodeRed detects it as a node, I have checked my package.json and it is following the documentation to be recognized as a node.

Comment: Does the module load on Windows if you use npm to install it manually in the `userDir`?

Comment: Yes, if I do npm install C:\\test\\testRemoteNodeWindow the module is loaded in ~\.node-red\node_modules.

Comment: But does it show up on the Node-RED palette after you have installed it?